# unit test strange things

Tags: visual-studio, moq, mstest, nsubstitute

i have a class extend from a base class,the base class in another dll.

```
public class MyMicroBlogCache : RelatedBase<THZUserInfo, MicroBlogCacheModel, int>
```

and in constructor,inject a ICache

```
public MyMicroBlogCache(ICache cache,....
```

in base class ,i use the ICache in a method(for example void A() )

and i write a unit test,mock the ICache

```
var cache = Substitute.For<ICache>();
cache.PageRelated<THZUserInfo, MicroBlogCacheModel, int>("My", 2217, 0, 3, out all, true)
.Returns(
    x =>
    {
        var list = new List<MicroBlogCacheModel>();
        list.Add(new MicroBlogCacheModel { Id = 1, UserId = 2217 });
        list.Add(new MicroBlogCacheModel { Id = 1, UserId = 2217 });
        list.Add(new MicroBlogCacheModel { Id = 1, UserId = 2217 });
        return list;
    });
```

mock with NSubstitute

```
var cache1 = new Mock<ICache>();
cache1.Setup(ca => ca.PageRelated<THZUserInfo, MicroBlogCacheModel, int>("My", 2217, 0, 3, out all, true))
.Returns(
() =>
{
    var list = new List<MicroBlogCacheModel>();
    list.Add(new MicroBlogCacheModel { Id = 1, UserId = 2217 });
    list.Add(new MicroBlogCacheModel { Id = 1, UserId = 2217 });
    list.Add(new MicroBlogCacheModel { Id = 1, UserId = 2217 });
    return list;
});
```

or mock with moq

and the strange thing is:
when i call the method write in base class(RelatedBase),the method(for example A()) call mock ICache,it not return the mock data.
if i override the method in child class(MyMicroBlogCache),and use the same code(override and copy the code from base class),it return the mock data.
if i override,and use base.A(...) ,it not return mock data.
so,when the code in base class,it wrong,and when code in child class,it right.
if i create a class implement ICache,it is ok
both NSubstitute and Moq are same.
i try this with vs2015,vs2013;.net 4.5
why it happens,and how can i fix it

**Update:**

```
        var cache1 = new Mock<ICache>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        cache1.Setup(ca => ca.PageRelated<THZUserInfo, MicroBlogCacheModel, int>("My", 2217, 0, 3, out all, true))
            .Returns(
            () =>
            {
                var list = new List<MicroBlogCacheModel>();
                list.Add(new MicroBlogCacheModel { Id = 1, UserId = 2217 });
                list.Add(new MicroBlogCacheModel { Id = 1, UserId = 2217 });
                list.Add(new MicroBlogCacheModel { Id = 1, UserId = 2217 });
                return list;
            });
```

then test method call

```
var r = my.GetRelatedPage(2217, 0, 3, out all, true);
```

in base class it call

```
var list = cache.PageRelated<TMainKey, TChild, TMainKey>("My", key, skip, take, out all, desc);
```

key=2217,skip=0,take=3,desc=true,

Answer (score 0):

You have a generic base class:

```
RelatedBase<T1, T2, T3>
```

you also have an inherited class without generic parameters, which specifies the type for each T1, T2, T3.

With genericity, `RelatedBase<THZUserInfo, MicroBlogCacheModel, int>` is not the same type as `RelatedBase<T1, T2, T3>`

Now: In your set-up, you explicitly Setup `ca.PageRelated<THZUserInfo, MicroBlogCacheModel, int>`

If, you call the method on the base class (the generic one) with different argument types, then it will not exactly be the same call as the one which was setup, and therefore, will return the default value for the method.

Try instantiating your Mock with `new Mock<ICache>(MockBehavior.MockStrict)` and you should have a `MockException` that confirms that.

Then, think of type arguments as proper arguments : if they don't match, then the setup doesn't apply.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: B:A<X,Y,Z> and A call m<T1,T2,T3>,so if i use B.m,it is m<X,Y,Z>.i don't understand why you say it not same,can you explain more?

Comment: and i try new Mock<ICache>(MockBehavior.MockStrict) it not throw MockException

Comment: can you add your moq setups to your question please ?

Comment: Is it the only setup? If not,  maybe post the whole test,  it will be easier.